# Quartic diophantine equation: $16r^4+112r^3+200r^2-112r+16=s^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations, problem-solving

Given this diophantine equation:
$$16r^4+112r^3+200r^2-112r+16=s^2$$

Wolfram alpha says the only solutions are $(r,s)=(0,\pm4)$

How would one prove these are the only solutions? Thanks.

Comment: **Hint:** $P(r)=s^2$ divides by $8,$ but not by $16.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are NOT the only integer solutions.

We also have $(-2, \pm 20)$ and $(-8, \pm 148)$.

Basically, the quartic is birationally equivalent to the elliptic curve
\begin{equation*}
V^2=U^3-142U^2+5040U
\end{equation*}
with
\begin{equation*}
r=\frac{7U-V-504}{4(63-U)}
\end{equation*}

The elliptic curve has $3$ finite torsion points of order $2$ at $(0,0)$, $(70,0)$ and $(72,0)$, which give $r=0,1/2,-2$. The curve has rank $1$ with a generator $(56,112)$, which gives $r=-8$.

Rank $1$ implies an infinite number of rational points which lead to an infinite number of rational values of $r$. I have not checked whether any more of these are integers.

Comment: is there a good source for this method of solving diophantine equations with elliptic curves?